# design and patterns - mvc4 (creating an email depending on the status)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, design-patterns

In a mvc4 application that creates messages, I want a good way to handle the email body depending on a status and other parameters.

I have a model message. Once I save the model in the controller, I call a `SendEmail(MessageModel message)` function that construct an email depending on the `SubbmittedBy` and the `Status` of the email.

```
SendEmail(MessageModel message){
    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
    msg.From = new MailAddress("me@me.com", "you");

    switch (MessageStatus)
    {
        case CASE_1 :
            if(SubbmittedBy == ...)
                string bod = "";
                bod.Append(message.Name);
                bod.Append(message.Date);
                bod.Append(message.Attribute2)

                msg.Subject = bod.Append(message.ID);
                msg.Body = "way #2" ;
                ...
            else
                msg.Subject = "way #5";
                msg.Body = "way #6" ;
                ...
        break;
        case status2 :
            if(SubbmittedBy == ...)
                msg.Subject = "way #3";
                msg.Body = "way #4" ;
                ...
            else
                ...
        break;
        case status3 :
            if(SubbmittedBy == ...)
                ...
            else
                ... 
        break;
        case status4 :
            if(SubbmittedBy == ...)
                ...
            else
                ... 
        break;
        case status5 :
            if(SubbmittedBy == ...)
                ...
            else
                ...
        break;
    }

    msg.IsBodyHtml = isBodyHtml;
    sc.Send(msg);
}
```

Is there any way to make it less complex and easier to read, by using a design pattern? My email append is like 100 lines for each `if(...)`. I have like a 1000 hundred lines of code, that are just not readable.

Comment: We had used the factory pattern. Based on the status instantiate the correct EmailType class and then used template pattern to build the body, subject, and message body. The email was constructed by reading different xml files and then applying XSLT.

Comment: Agree with Nilesh. Factory is a right thing to do.